# Fill the section of an ellipse with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm learning TikZ and I would like to learn how to fill a ellipse section determined by the center and two points on the curve wich coordinates are, obviously, known. I mean something like this:

[image: pretended result]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps this post can be useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406725/what-is-the-meaning-of-that-code

Answer (score 4):

A simple approach using polar coordinates that does not require clipping:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
        \draw (0:0) ellipse (4 and 3);
        \draw[fill=red] (0:0) -- (-20:4 and 3) arc (-20:115:4 and 3) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Polar coordinates in Ti*k*Z are defines as `(t:r)` where `t` is the angular coordinate and `r` the radial coordinate (that is the distance from the center). The radius of the ellipse (which is equal to that of the arc part of the sector) is `4 and 3` which means that the larger radius is 4cm and the smaller radius is 3cm. This radius is also used as radial coordinate for the starting point of the arc of the sector.

Comment: Definitely a better solution than mine.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with clipping around the ellipse.

[image: Fill ellipse sector]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\a{-20} \def\b{115} % Angles for the filling
        \def\r{4} \def\R{3}     % Radii of the ellipse
        \def\ell{(0,0) ellipse (\r cm and \R cm)}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip \ell;
            \filldraw[red,draw=black,thick] (0,0) -- (\a:2*\r cm) |- (\b:2*\r cm)-- cycle;  
        \end{scope}             
        \draw[thick] \ell;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For a more regular and clever solution, have a look at [this complete answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393247/how-to-draw-right-arc-of-ellipse-with-tikz).